# How to mod rewrite this URL correctly?

Tags: .htaccess, rest, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am adding a REST API to my application. The REST API is located at /api of my app. I want to route all requests correctly including requests that have parameters. I have the following htaccess rules which are working for the most part:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Using these rules, I can now go to:
mysite.com/api/projects/get and it will correctly give me back JSON data as if I would have accessed it the regular way mysite.com?url=api/projects/get

My problem begins when I try to add parameters to the request.
My application will already handle parameters. So if I were to go to: mysite.com/api/projects&type=1, it will give me back the projects of type 1. However, I think it is expected that the URL would look more like: mysite.com/api/projects?type=1 (note the ? instead of the &)

How would I modify my htaccess rules to handle this?

I was trying the following but with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&$2 [L]
```

Comment: If you are doing friendly URL's and are capturing the entire URI which is what it looks like, then just add it to the end instead of doing a query string. `/api/projects/get/1` and in your code you know the last path of 1 is the type if it is present. You should stay with one method IMO and not over complicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the Query String Append flag, as shown below:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Per the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html):

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.
>
> Consider the following rule:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule "/pages/(.+)" "/page.php?page=$1" [QSA]
> ```
>
> With the `[QSA]` flag, a request for `/pages/123?one=two` will be mapped to
>   `/page.php?page=123&one=two`. Without the `[QSA]` flag, that same request
>   will be mapped to `/page.php?page=123` - that is, the existing query
>   string will be discarded.

Comment: Thanks, the QSA flag was the key here.